# Qt GUI and Business Logic modules

Tags: c++, qt, module, calculator

I want to separate this project [Qt Calculator Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html) into the GUI module and the Business Logic module. What is the best way to do so and is it better to write the logic module in only C++, so that I can use it in other IDE's as well?

Comment: MVC pattern, combined with the rule that a model should NOT use Qt types, will take you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice or design pattern in your case is [GRASP Controller](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1499/software-patterns-grasp-part-iv-controller) pattern.

In your case - it means you shall separate class `Calculator` from Qt stuff (like `QWidget`) completely.

So - if you need to present something from `Calculator` to Qt widgets - create and use interface like `CalculatorPresentationInterface`.

To get some callbacks, GUI events to calculator - make callbacks slots, or interface  `CalculatorConrollerInterface`.

So - your calculator will implement `CalculatorConrollerInterface` to be able to receive events from GUI.

Use [dependency injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to inject your `Calculator` via `CalculatorConrollerInterface` to your GUI.

Your GUI shall implement (or you can use [adapter pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm)) `CalculatorPresentationInterface` and you shall inject your GUI via `CalculatorPresentationInterface` to your real `Calculator` class.

In this way both layers Business logic layer (Calculator) and presentation logic (Qt GUI) will be separated from each other and you can easily exchange both layers.

---

An example (each class in separate file).

Interfaces:

```
 class CalculatorConrollerInterface
 {
 public:
     virtual void onAdd() = 0;
     virtual void onCurrentNumberChange(int number) = 0;
 };
 class CalculatorPresentationInterface
 {
 public:
     virtual void showResult(int result) = 0;
 };
```

The calculator - shall not have any connection to Qt:

```
 class Calculator  : public CalculatorConrollerInterface
 {
 public:
      Calculator(CalculatorPresentationInterface& presentation)
        : presentation(presentation)
      {}
     virtual void onAdd() override
     { 
        // no idea this is correct - just example
        previousNumber = previousNumber + currentNumber;
        currentNumber = 0;
        presentation.showResult(previousNumber );
     }

     void onCurrentNumberChange(int number) override
     {
          currentNumber  = number;
     }
private:
      CalculatorPresentationInterface& presentation;
      // all stuff necessary to calculate
      int previousNumber;
      int currentNumber;
 };
```

Qt presentation for calculator:

```
 class QtCalculatorPresentation : public CalculatorPresentationInterface
 {
 public:
     void setController(CalculatorConrollerInterface& controller)
     {
        this->controller = &controller;
     }
     void showResult(int result) override;

 private:
    CalculatorConrollerInterface* controller;
    // plus all Qt widgets necessary
    // and they shall forward any event to controller
 };
```

And your main:

```
 #include "Calculator.hpp"
 #include "QtCalculatorPresentation .hpp"

 int main()
 {
      // dependency injections
      QtCalculatorPresentation  qtPresentation;
      Calculator calculator(qtPresentation);
      qtPresentation.setController(calculator);

      qtPresentation.exec();
 }
```

Comment: Given that Qt is an application development framework, the obsession with keeping business logic not using Qt is IMHO unwarranted. You're losing out on signals/slots, introspection, threading, messaging (events), etc... For a calculator business object, you really should be using a state machine, like QStateMachine, since these things are *notoriously* hard to get right, and example code with wrong functionality is almost omnipresent on the web precisely because people don't bother to specify the statechart for the system.

Comment: With Qt you don't need the straitjacket of a fixed interface class with virtual methods specifying the interface. It's very easy to connect heterogenous clients and providers using signals/slots; functors can be used to adapt a non-conforming provider to the needs of a client, etc. As far as I'm concerned, the classical "interface as an abstract class" pattern is highly inflexible and very hard to use (or absent!) when you interface with 3rd party code. Usually the interfaces are not given as abstract classes, but concrete classes with just one implementation defining the API.

Comment: @KubaOber - 1) In C++14+boost you have everything you can imagine Qt will ever provide. 2) If you really need some qt state-machine/qt timers etc.. - then in the very same way you can create one in Qt - and connect via C++ interface to you "business Controller" - so it can use abstract timers etc...

Comment: @KubaOber 3) I always do this way - it is very easy to use - just a matter of taste - and OP wanted to try this way 4) singnal/slots use in your Qt world classes - no problem and even advisable - but out of it - only C++ interfaces to connect to your business logic - alternatively use `std::function` or `boost::signal`...

Comment: "In C++14+boost you have everything you can imagine Qt will ever provide" Not introspection :)

Comment: @KubaOber AFAIK - works ongoing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206420/compile-time-reflection-in-c1z - 2017 is coming... Anyway - I do not see much usage of introspection for business logic...