# C++ function to output generic struct

Tags: c++, function, templates, struct

I would like to know how to write a C++ function to print the attributes of a generic struct. For example,

```
struct a {
std::string field_1;
std::string field_2;
std::string field_3;
};


struct b {
int a;
int b;
int c;
};
```

The function would take struct of form 'a' or 'b'as inputs and generate outputs. Perhaps a template could be used -- if so how would one build it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in standard C++, it does not work this way. C++ [does not have reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: This wouldn't be too difficult in Java. Surprised it's not possible in C++

Comment: @KAlistair Indeed, but Java and C++ are actually very different

Comment: Java is a managed language. C++ is not. Managed languages are fundamentally different from natively-compiled languages, like C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible but might be available in C++17 with static reflection.

See also [Compile-time reflection in C++1z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206420/compile-time-reflection-in-c1z)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to work around the missing support for reflections in c++.

The first one is to use std::tuple instead and iterate over it. This can be done explicitly by reflection or nicely wrapped in boost::fusion.

The second posibillity with c++14 is boost::hana. In boost::hana there are structs, that can be iterated over. This is done with the help of preprocessor macros.

If you are still interested, i can post a minimal example here.